# Applying count function to data frame gives different result

Tags: python, pandas, list, count

so i have a list with swear words, of which I want to count the occurrence in a data frame.     `swear_words = ['ass', 'cunt']`

I created the function

```
def br(row):
    count = sum([row.count(word) for word in swear_words])
    return count
```

this works when i use `print(br(rd))` as it returns 2 for `rd =['bass', 'ass', 'sex', 'cunt']`

however, when I apply this function to my pandas dataframe, where the row tokenW is also ['bass', 'ass', 'sex', 'cunt'], the function returns 3, probably because it counts bass as ass.

```
df['test'] = df.apply(lambda x: br(x['tokenW']), axis=1)
```

What is going wrong?

```
import pandas as pd

swear_words = ['ass', 'cunt']

data = [[['bass', 'ass', 'sex', 'cunt']]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['tokenW'])

rd =['bass', 'ass', 'sex', 'cunt']
def br(row):
    count = sum([row.count(word) for word in swear_words])
    return count

print(br(rd))
df['test'] = df.apply(lambda x: br(x['tokenW']), axis=1)
print(df['test'])
```

Comment: Would you include a [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (a small bit of code that we can easily copy and run)?

Comment: Just added a MRE

Comment: The code you posted produces `2` and `2` for me. As an aside you could rewrite the statement to `df['test'] = df['tokenW'].apply(br)`

Comment: Does `df['test'] = df['tokenW'].explode().isin(swear_words).sum(level=0)` work for you?

Comment: This codes work for me as well, but it produces 3 when I use an existing database ```df = pd.read_csv("firga.csv")``` eventhough the values are the same as ```rd```